Filter agenda view on the absence of effort property
I'm looking a way to filter tasks in my emacs org agenda on the lack of effort in the property.
I've figured out how to filter on the effort when it is detailed but I cannot figure out when there is no effort info.
I've tried EFFORT=0 in the C-c a m EFFORT=0 and it works.
But progamatically, I'm unable to do the same.
In the org-agenda-custom-commands, (tags "EFFORT=0") does not work.
To be more accurate, here is what's not working:
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      ;; l'idée est d'avoir la liste des éléments à classer et ou à traiter
      ;; et d'avoir les elements delegues comme reminder
      '(("g" "Get Things Done (GTD)"
         ((agenda "Future"
                  (;(org-agenda-skip-function
                    ;'(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'deadline))
                   (org-deadline-warning-days 0)
                   (org-agenda-span 1))) ;; 1 following days only
          (agenda nil
                  ((org-agenda-entry-types '(:deadline))
                   (org-agenda-format-date "")
                   (org-agenda-span 0)
                   ;(org-deadline-warning-days 14)
                   ;(org-agenda-skip-function
                   ; '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'notregexp "\\* NEXT"))
                   (org-agenda-overriding-header "Deadlines")))

      ;; tâches déléguées à autrui qu'il faut checker
      (todo "DELEGATED on HOLD"
        (
         (org-agenda-prefix-format " %i %-12:c [%e] ")
         (org-agenda-overriding-header "Delegated on hold to check")
         ))

      ;; mails
      (todo "TODO"
        (
        (org-agenda-overriding-header "Emails to treat")
        (org-agenda-prefix-format " %-14:c ")
        (org-agenda-files '("../org/mail.org"))
        ))
      
      ;; tâches dans inbox qu'il faut évaluer et classer
      (todo "TODO"
        (
         (org-agenda-overriding-header "To Evaluate and Refile")
         (org-agenda-prefix-format "  %i %-12:c ")
                 (org-agenda-files '("../org/inbox.org"))
         ))

      ;; tâches avec effort de moins de 15 minutes qu'il est inutile de planifier
      (todo "TODO"
        (
         (org-agenda-overriding-header "Fast to be done")
         (org-agenda-prefix-format " %-12:c [%e] ")
         (org-agenda-skip-function 'guillaume/org-search-for-quickpicks)
         )
        )

      ;; identifier les tâches avec effort non renseigné
      ;; THIS IS BELOW WHAT'S NOT WORKING
      (todo "TODO"
                (
                 (org-agenda-skip-function
                  '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'regexp "TRIGGER" 'regexp "BLOCKER" 'scheduled 'deadline)
                  )
         (org-tags-view nil TODO "EFFORT=\"\"")
         (org-agenda-prefix-format "  %i %-12:c [%e] ")
                 (org-agenda-overriding-header "Someday")
         ;; all todo sauf ceux de inbox
         (org-agenda-files (remove "~/Dropbox/org/inbox.org" org-agenda-files))
                 )
                )
          ))))

This does not sort tasks without effort but shows all of them...
Any hint?

"This does not sort tasks without effort but shows all of them... " - of course it shows all of them: it's a TODO list - on what criteria are you expecting that they would be sorted? In any case, that was not part of the original question (which asks for "filtering", not "sorting"). If you provide details about the sorting that you want, I can perhaps be convinced to add to the answer (if it's not too much work). But I hope that you heed the lesson: you can only expect answers based on the question you ask, not on the one that exists only in your head: we cannot read your thoughts.

For sorting, do C-h v org-agenda-sorting-strategy.

You are misunderstanding how org-agenda-custom-commands is structured. It's a complicated variable, so you really need to read its documentation, experiment with small-scale examples and add one feature at a time. In particular, things like (org-agenda-overriding-header "Someday") are variable settings, not function calls. So you cannot add a function call like  (org-tags-view nil TODO "EFFORT=\"\"") in there: that's what you would do in your own function, but in org-agenda-custom-commands, you would use the tags type with a "EFFORT=\"\"" matching pattern as shown in my answer.

Perhaps a better way to check for a non-existent property is to look for the empty string: C-c a m EFFORT="" RET - or you can check which ones do have the property with its negation: C-c a m EFFORT<>"".
To do it programmatically, you need to find out which function C-c a m calls: doing C-h k C-c a tells you that C-c a calls org-agendaand reading that function's doc string with C-h f org-agenda tells you:
m     Call ‘org-tags-view’ to display headlines with tags matching
      a condition  (the user is prompted for the condition).

and checking the doc string of org-tags-view with C-h f org-tags-view shows you how to call it:
(org-tags-view &optional TODO-ONLY MATCH)

Show all headlines for all ‘org-agenda-files’ matching a TAGS criterion.
The prefix arg TODO-ONLY limits the search to TODO entries.

So try
(org-tags-view nil "EFFORT=\"\"")

You need to escape the double quotes inside the string.
For an Org agenda custom command, then try the following:
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
   '("E" "Agenda entries without an effort property"
     tags "EFFORT=\"\""))


Thanks a lot for your time. For a specific agenda view, this works perfectly. But in a customized agenda view, this does not work as follows. Cannot I combine (org-tags-view nil "EFFORT=\"\"") to other specifications?

I don't understand: the last one IS a custom agenda view. How exactly does your non-working custom agenda view look? What's not working? Please update your question - although you should have included the custom agenda view in your question in the first place. That would avoid us going around in circles.

I've edited the question. Hope this is clearer. Thank you for your time

See my third comment under your question about your question in the comment above: the short answer is no,  See the settings description in the doc string of org-agenda-custom-commands - it says: settings  A list of option settings, similar to that in a let form, so like  this: ((opt1 val1) (opt2 val2) ...).   The values will be evaluated at the moment of execution, so quote them when needed. IOW, they are variable settings, not function calls.
